# Sind »Oh man!« und »O Mann!« gleichbedeutend und handelt es sich um einen Anglizismus / Germanismus?

Tags: loanword, interjection

Manchmal nutze ich auf Deutsch die Englische Phrase »Oh man!«.
Deutsche sagen auch gelegentlich »O Mann!« (deutsch).

Dem Wortlaut nach scheint es keinen Unterschied zwischen dem englischen »Oh man!« und dem deutschen »O Mann!« zu geben.

Ist die deutsche Interjektion von der englischen abgeleitet, oder umgekehrt, oder sind sie unabhängig voneinander entstanden?
Und: Sind die beiden Interjektionen gleichbedeutend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Oh Mann!

wird tatsächlich im Deutschen ziemlich oft benutzt, wenn man Enttäuschung und Bedauern mit einem Ausruf zum Ausdruck bringen will, im Gegensatz zu

> Mannomann!

mit dem man u.A. Erstaunen zum Ausdruck bringt.

Ich halte es allerdings für sehr unwahrscheinlich, dass der Ausdruck aus dem Englischen übernommen wurde, sondern eher für eine sehr naheliegende parallele Entwicklung. Der Ausruf "Oh" ist sozusagen international, und dass "Mann" und "man" gleich klingen ist der gemeinsamen Sprachgeschichte geschuldet.

Comment: "mannomann" wird auch als Ausdruck der Verzweiflung oder Unverstaendnis verwendet

Comment: Dass das ganze eine Interjektion ist, erkennt man daran, dass auch Mädchen einander zurufen: Hey man!

Answer (score 0):

> Manchmal habe ich die Englische Phrase "Oh man!" in deutschem Kontext
>   benutzt, und ich glaube deutsche Leute sagen es manchmal auch.

Es ist ein Unterschied, was ein Wort bedeutet und was die Mensch meinen, was sie damit sagen. Und das ist nicht unbedingt eine Frage der Übersetzung sondern des Gebrauchs.

aber daran denken wohl nicht einmal die Amerikaner mehr.
erstaunlich ist ja, dass selbst die Mädchen zu einander sagen: hey, man!

richtig wäre doch: hey, Frau!

Also: **Hey Mann! bzw. Oh man! = Ausruf**

Comment: da kommt mir gerade in den Sinn: Unsere Nachbarn sind “evangelicos”. Die junge Mama kommt neulich mit ihrer Kleinen zu Besuch ihrer Eltern und ruft schon von weitem über den Gartenzaun zu ihrer Mutti: “ Mami, Mami, weisst du was? Aimy, ( das ist die Kleine) hat heute zum erstenmal AMEN gesagt.” Oh,Mann, von AMEN zu oh man ist nur ein kleiner Schritt! Ich kann sie schon hören ...

Comment: Es macht viel Spass mit Dir zu diskutieren, Oida ey ;-)

Comment: Danke gleichfalls! Amen.